# using trig to find speed in vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

A spring gun at ground level fires a golf ball at an angle of $45°$. The ball lands $10$ m away. What is the initial speed?

I know there is a physics equation that ties this all together but I want to try the vector way.
SO far I have done:

$$r''(t) = (0, -9.8)$$
$$r'(t) = (c_1, -9.8t + c_2)$$
I also know that $r'(0) = (c_1, c_2)$ and the magnitude of the is the initial speed but I have no idea how to find it. I was told to write $c_1$ and $c_2$ in terms of the unknown speed but I don't know exactly how to do that. I tried $\cos45 = \dfrac {c_1} {speed}$ ?? But I have no idea if this is right.

Comment: You know that $r'(0)=(v_0 \cos(45),v_0 \sin(45))$ and $r(0)=(0,0)$ which tells you $$r(t)=\Big(v_0t \cos(45),-4.9t^2+v_0t \sin(45)\Big)$$ Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: This belongs on physics.se but they are much less receptive to homework problems.

Comment: This is actually part of my multivaribale class

Comment: @MatthewHolder yes I do! thank you so much, I actually had written that down but did not connect the dots, ever

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos 45^\circ = \sin 45^\circ$, you have $c_1=c_2$  The horizontal motion equation gives you the time of flight as a function of $c_1$  The vertical motion equation gives you the time of flight as a function of $c_2$.  Since $c_1=c_2$ you have enough for a solution.